# Pasar array bidimensional a PHP por formulario

Tags: php, html

Hola tengo una tarea en **php** y mi profesor tiene por filosofía que nos busquemos la vida, tengo este código, pero no sé como pasarselo a php para que lo recoja y lo guarde en un **array bidimensional:** Agradecería mucho la ayuda

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="como[0][0]" id="como1" value="Web">
    <label for="como1">Una web</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="como[0][1]" id="como2" value="Google">
    <label for="como2">Google</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="como[1][0]" id="como3" value="Anuncio en prensa">
    <label for="como3">Anuncio en prensa</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="como[1][1]" id="como4" value="Anuncio en tv">
    <label for="como4">Anuncio en tv</label>

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>

    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Hola Richard... siento decirte que (normalmente) esta comunidad no hacen tareas escolar de otros... y más aún si no haz hecho ningún mínimo de esfuerzo por tu parte... intenta primero y vuelvo cuando tengas una pregunta especifica...

Comment: De nada... pero si quieres recibir ayuda tienes que tener una duda especifica... y en tú código no veo ni una linea de PHP... ósea que tendríamos hacer tu _tarea escolar_. Si lo entiendes hasta aquí deberías visitar el [tour](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help)... un buen día igualmente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He probado y esta funcionando correctamente para mi, php me devuelve que estoy enviando esto (usando var_dump($_POST))

```
array(1) {
  ["como"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      [1]=>
      string(6) "Google"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [1]=>
      string(13) "Anuncio en tv"
    }
  }
}
```

Si lo q te refieres es que no sabes como hacer para usar el metodo post y la accion enviarla a un fichero determinado en el tag  debes hacer algo asi

```
<form action="file_that_read_the_array.php" method="POST">
```

Comment: muchas gracias, era esa mi duda, sabía meterlo en un array unidimensional pero no tenía ni idea de hacerlo asi, gracias :D

Comment: nada :D si puedes aceptar la respuesta por favor